# Adding array item to existing header tag, as data-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am currently building a website in expressionengine and would like to place a dynamic data-toggle to some header 3 tags that are also dynamically displayed on the webpage. When a user creates a "section" on the website it creates a `<h3>` and `<div>` which contains the information they input. This is all working fine however I wish to apply a data-toggle to the header 3 tag using Javascript (and an ID to the div once this is sorted). I have created a piece of javascript which follows:

```
$(function(){
  {exp:channel:entries channel="page" dynamic="yes"}
    var toggles = new Array(
      {body}"{section_title}"{if row_count != total_rows},{/if}{/body}
    );
  {/exp:channel:entries}

  $.each( toggles, function( i, val ) {
    $('.about-content h3').attr("data-toggle", val);
  });
});
```

There is some expressionengine code in there but that is essentially a loop. So what happens is the loop grabs the title of sections on the webpage and then plonks int into the array. This all works fine and the output is as follows:

`var toggles = new Array("Values","Accreditations","Careers","Downloads");`

*side note: I'm going to remove capitalised characters and spaces once this bit is sorted*

I haven't used arrays in JavaScript / jQuery before so I am struggling to output each entry as a data-toggle for h3 tags that are generated dynamically further in the page. The `<h3>` tags are already there so don't need to be created with the function.

So there will be, in this example, four `<h3>` tags in a row. Can I go through each array item, and add the item to each `<h3>` one after another?

At present when I inspect the element with Firebug it displays the code as such:

```
<h3 data-toggle="Downloads">Values</h3>
<h3 data-toggle="Downloads">Accreditations</h3>
<h3 data-toggle="Downloads">Careers</h3>
<h3 data-toggle="Downloads">Downloads</h3>
```

But if I look at the source it displays as:

```
<h3 data-toggle="">Values</h3>
<h3 data-toggle="">Accreditations</h3>
<h3 data-toggle="">Careers</h3>
<h3 data-toggle="">Downloads</h3>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: As you are adding attributes using jQuery it will be visible using inspect element with Firebug but not with source. Since source show what is rendered by web server

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that part up :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to suss this out if anyone is interested.

```
$(function(){
  {exp:channel:entries channel="page" dynamic="yes"}
    var toggles = new Array(
      {body}"{section_title}"{if row_count != total_rows},{/if}{/body}
    );
  {/exp:channel:entries}

  $('.about-content h3').each(function(val) {
    $(this).attr("data-toggle" , toggles[val]);
  });
});
```

As I understand (which I probably don't) I'm just saying for each `.about-content h3` add an entry of the array as the data-toggle attribute.